# How to create multiple functions declaration in C?

Tags: c, gcc, cmsis

I want to add 400 Interrupt_Handler in https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/blob/develop/Device/ARM/ARMCM33/Source/startup_ARMCM33.c.

Mechanical approach is to add them in following way:

```
void Interrupt10_Handler     (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
void Interrupt11_Handler     (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
void Interrupt12_Handler     (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
....
void Interrupt400_Handler     (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
```

Is there any alternate way to add them? Something like following?

```
for($i=0;$i<=400;$i++) {
void Interrupt$i\_Handler     (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
}
```

Comment: those interrupt usually mean something. This job is pointless. Manufacturers supply you with the proper names. Using Interrupt134_Handler instead of DMA1_IRQHandler is rather pointless.

Comment: I am the one who is manufacturing :). If you see, Interrupt134_Handler is mapped to Default_Handler. And I will use Default_Handler symbol in vector.S file to route to custom handler passed in the testcase.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the source code. But write 3 lines C program. Then copy and paste.

```
int main (void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) printf("void Interrupt%d_Handler     (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias(\"Default_Handler\")));\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hnKznT

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a macro.
First step is to substitute i into the name

```
#define X(i) void Interrupt##i##_Handler     (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
```

Next step is to call the macro 400 times. It is possible without 400 lines using recursive macros:

```
#define X2(i) X(i) X(i+1)
#define X4(i) X2(i) X2(i+2)
...
```